# Do threads get its own timeslice in user processes?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I can explain the question better with an example so I am using it?

Suppose our system is Round-Robin scheduled system with each time interval for execution 10ms. If we create two threads in our program , will each thread be executing 10ms or both in combine will execute 10ms?

If they take combine 10ms then who manages context switching between threads?

Note: I am not talking about kernel threads here.

Comment: I think, since each thread is considered as a task, so each thread will get it's own timeslice i.e. time interval of 10msec. Switching takes place based on the time slice.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the threads contend for CPU with every other thread in the system. In POSIX terms, the threads have system contention scope.

Thus, for your example, each thread will get 10ms.

You can check this by:

1. Trying to set (via `pthread_attr_setscope`) the contention scope attribute to `PTHREAD_SCOPE_PROCESS` - should result in an error.
2. Get a thread attrbutes via `pthread_getattr_np` and check via `pthread_attr_getscope` that
   the contention scope is `PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM`

Answer (score 0):

Yes they too do have a time-slice.

In linux, threads vye for the resources such as memory,CPU or are waiting for some I/O event to occur. These threads under go through various states like idle,active,ready depending on the avalaibity of the resources. This all working is taken care by "Process Management Subsystem" which consists of Process Schedulars and manages the processes execution and their states.
One can also manipulate the time-period that a process can hold a resource like CPU.
Or the priority of a process can be changed( For e.g "nice").

-Sumeet